# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 22005

Tags: codeigniter

I need help on this please, I am new to CI.

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'bdate LIKE '%9/27/2015%' escape '!'}'.

SELECT SUM(amount) as score FROM paid WHERE bdate LIKE '%9/27/2015%' {escape '!'}

Filename: D:/BYCI/application/models/income.php

Line Number: 7
```

Below is the code

```
$d = date("M j Y",strtotime('today'));
$date4paid = date("n/j/o",strtotime($d));
$this->db->select('SUM(amount) as score');
$q = $this->db->get_where('paid',array('bdate' => date("n/j/o",strtotime($d))),0,0);
$row=$q->row();
return $score=$row->score;
```

The code below works but it gives me wrong output. I need to get the total income for the day.

```
$d = date("M j Y",strtotime('today')); 
$date4paid = date("n/j/o",strtotime($d)); 
$this->db->select('SUM(amount) as score'); 
$arr = array('bdate' => $date4paid); 
$q=$this->db->get('paid'); 
$this->db->like($arr);
$row=$q->row();
return $score=$row->score;
```

I have done almost everything for a week now and still I can't figure it out. I am using CI 3.0 version

thank you.

Comment: has nothing to do with CI and everything to do with SQL syntax.

Comment: May i know what's the correct syntax is? I am using active record.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `LIKE` use `WHERE` 
Try using the below query,Where clause helps you to result the data of specific date.

```
$this->db->select('SUM(amount) as score');
$this->db->where('bdate',$date4paid); 
$q=$this->db->get('paid')->row();
```

Comment: This answer is not userfull.

Comment: Please consider that date is not alone, we have also datetime, and you cannot point to a specific date and time. This is were the `LIKE` will be used because you will only compare the date ex. **wrong** `2015-09-29 == 2015-09-29 10:15:45` | **correct** `2015-09-29 10:15:45 LIKE #2015-09-29#`

Comment: Ok,but  the error chance can be of your query only,have you tried echo your query and run it in phpmyadmin?

Comment: it;s `ODBC` and using active record. ^_^